# Reference error when running k6: regeneratorRuntime is not defined

Tags: reactjs, testing, load-testing, k6

I had k6 up and running, but now every time I try and run a test I am getting this error: ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined.

I have tried installing and importing babel, which some people have suggested, but it did not work.

```
import http from "k6/http";
import { check } from "k6";

async function registerHandlers() {
    const dataForBody = 'client_id=LoadTesting&grant_type=client_credentials&' +
      `scope=${encodeURI('StitchApi')}&` +
      `client_secret=${encodeURI(process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_SECRET)}`;
    const messageHeaders = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    };
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: process.env.REACT_APP_STITCH_AUTH_URL,
      headers: messageHeaders,
      data: dataForBody,
    }).then((response) => {
        return response;
    }).catch((error) =>
      global.console.log('axios error: ', error)
    )
  }
// const queries = JSON.parse(open("./easygraphql-load-tester-queries.json"));
const url = "https://mywebsite.net/Api/GraphQL/";
const authorization = registerHandlers();
console.log("AUTH!!!!!!", authorization);
const payload = JSON.stringify({
    query: `
    {
        student(id: "5asdfasdfasdfasdf") {
        name
        }
    }
    ` });
const params = {
    headers: {
        "authorization": "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf",
        "content-type": "application/json",
    }
}

export default function () {
    // console.log('query: ', queries);
    let res = http.post(url, payload, params);
    check(res, {
        "status is 200": (r) => r.status === 200,
        "is authenticated": (r) => r.json().authenticated === true,
        "is correct user": (r) => r.json().user === "user",
        "caption is correct": (r) => r.html("h1").text() == "Example Domain",
    });
};
```

I just want my load testing to work!

EDIT:

I am using 
    `"@babel/core": "^7.4.0",`

and my babel.rc file looks like:

```
{
  "presets": [ "es2015", "stage-0" ]
}
```

Comment: What's your babel version? Also plz post your .babelrc, or babel.config.js.

Comment: I updated the post to have that information. Thank you for reminding me to add that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are using Promises, but k6 at the moment doesn't have [an event loop](https://github.com/loadimpact/k6/issues/882). So your code won't be able to work and babel unfortunately can't help here :(.

Additionally you are trying to use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios), but you don't  import it, and it will also (probably) not work as it won't have support for k6, given it is neither a browser nor node.js ;).

All you need to get it working though is to use k6's http library instead of axios to get your authorization and to not use `async`. Also `global` is node.js specific AFAIK>